# How to add random str in laravel input

Tags: php, laravel

I have clone methode where i can duplicate (clone) my products but my title column is `unique` and I can't clone my products what i need is to add some random text or numbers before or after my title in order to be allowed to save new entry.

How can I add that str in my title?

here is my method:

```
public function clonemaker($id)
    {
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      $newProduct->title = str_before('clone', 'title');
      $newProduct = $product->replicate();
      $newProduct->save();

      return redirect()->route('products.index')
          ->with('info',
           'Product Cloned');
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: makes no sense why you made the title column unique, but if anyhow its necessary then try using php's  `time()` function to make cloned product's title unique.
Example- `$newProduct->title = time() . 'product_title';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

here is the solution:

```
public function clonemaker($id)
    {
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      $title = $product->title;
      $newProduct = $product->replicate();
      $newProduct->title = str_before('cloned' .'_'. $title, 'dijd');
      $newProduct->save();

      return redirect()->route('products.index')
          ->with('info',
           'Product Cloned');
    }
```

This will add new product name such as `clone_product`.

To answer @devsourav , I have to say it does make sense when your slug comes from your title it has to be unique in order to avoid 2 product with same slug.

PS: I really wish to know the person who doesn't know the answer and gave `-` to this question :)) some people are just hatred! with no reason.

Hope this help others.

Comment: I didn't downvote - but I'd argue that a better solution would be to *not* make the product title unique (that's what the `id` is for), especially if you're selling books or music (how many albums are called "Greatest Hits")...

Comment: @CD001 Question 4u: how do you avoid duplicate slug when you are using sluggable package (also you want to have seo friendly slugs so you don't want to mix your title with other inputs in order to get unique slug), how do you do that?

Comment: If call twice for the same id, it will fail because there is already one cloned_.$title .
I did not downvote your answer but @devsourav solution seem better.

Comment: @Radu it's not about ID see imagine you have post id 1 title & slug is `xxx1` and  then you have post id 2 title and slug is `xxx1` also now how users want to access (both slugs are same)? that's why my title is unique. `As I mentioned before I use sluggable package which retrieve title to slug` if my title not be unique my slug will not be also and that's when the problems will pop up.

Comment: If you would like to have a unique slug without adding a unique constraint to your field title, you can just append the id to your title after saving. That way, every slug will be unique.

Comment: @mafortis - same way Magento does it, store the slugs separate from the product titles and have them manually editable (and unique). So a product called "Greatest Hits" by the artist "Queen" could have the URL slug "queen-greatest-hits"

Comment: @CD001 that's what I mentioned in my comment before `don't want to mix your title with other inputs` such as singer name + my e-commerce app doesn't sell music albums and there is no other good inputs for slug. I guess the best way to avoid duplicate slug is to title be unique.

Comment: @PaulSantos then wouldn't be ugly? example: `laptop-asus-l455-2000` then users think i have 1999 more l455 laptop which is in fact only id of that post :)